How to get the full reasoning history of vertexai LangchainAgent
How I can see the full reasoning history of a vertexai.preview.reasoning_engines.LangchainAgent after calling the query method - I have tried setting return_intermediate_steps to True in model_kwargs and agent_executor_kwargs, but this only prints the tool function calls. Setting verbose to true in kwargs also does not work. I've also tried out a callback manager in agent_executor_kwargs, but the manager does not show the reasoning, again it only shows the function calls.
Here is the LangchainAgent class: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/reference/python/latest/vertexai.preview.reasoning_engines.LangchainAgent
This is a real problem, because the ReAct agent in the pure langchain package makes it easy to see the full reasoning chain.
What I tried: I instantiated a LangchainAgent with the model set to "gemini-1.5-pro-001", defined a callback handler subclassing BaseCallbackHandler and implemented on_agent_action() and on_llm_end(), called the query method on the agent. I want to see all the steps the agent goes through including "thinking" steps. Instead, I can only see invoke steps, with no explanation for why the agent called them.

YourEnv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py
enter image description here
try to ouput "chunk"

Can you explain a bit more please

The 'chunk' variable in this file is the output of each model thought process, including all previous steps. This is the system file for Langchain, and you need to find it in the conda environment you created to debug or print it. The file path is "YourEnv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py"

@manHu please consider adding the entire relevant code portion as text in the answer, instead of linking images that contain code.
